# Editing configmap.yml and elasticsearch.yml in order to change password

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-storage

I want to implement a jaeger installation with persistent storage using elasticsearch like backend on my Kubernetes cluster on Google cloud platform.

I am using the jaeger kubernetes templates and I am starting with elasticsearch [production setup](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes#production-setup).

I've downloaded and modified the [`configmap.yml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/production-elasticsearch/configmap.yml) file in order to change the password field value and the [`elasticsearch.yml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/production-elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml) file in order to fix the password value which I've changed.

My customized `.yml` files has stayed of this way:

`configmap.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jaeger-configuration
  labels:
    app: jaeger
    jaeger-infra: configuration
data:
  span-storage-type: elasticsearch
  collector: |
    es:
      server-urls: http://elasticsearch:9200
      username: elastic
      password: **my-password-value**
    collector:
      zipkin:
        http-port: 9411
  query: |
    es:
      server-urls: http://elasticsearch:9200
      username: elastic
      password:  **my-password-value**
  agent: |
    collector:
      host-port: "jaeger-collector:14267"
```

`elasticsearch.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
  kind: StatefulSet
  metadata:
    name: elasticsearch
    labels:
      app: jaeger
      jaeger-infra: elasticsearch-statefulset
  spec:
    serviceName: elasticsearch
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: jaeger-elasticsearch
          jaeger-infra: elasticsearch-replica
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: elasticsearch
            image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.0
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command:
              - bin/elasticsearch
            args:
              - "-Ehttp.host=0.0.0.0"
              - "-Etransport.host=127.0.0.1"
            volumeMounts:
              - name: data
                mountPath: /data
            readinessProbe:
              exec:
                command:
                - curl
                - --fail
                - --silent
                - --output
                - /dev/null
                - --user
                - elastic:**my-password-value**
                - localhost:9200
              initialDelaySeconds: 5
              periodSeconds: 5
              timeoutSeconds: 4
        volumes:
          - name: data
            emptyDir: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: elasticsearch
    labels:
      app: jaeger
      jaeger-infra: elasticsearch-service
  spec:
    clusterIP: None
    selector:
      app: jaeger-elasticsearch
    ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: elasticsearch
    - port: 9300
      name: transport
```

And then, I've created the kubernetes cluster configuration with the new password value from my machine to my KGE via `kubectl` command

```
~/w/j/AddPersistVolumToPods ❯❯❯ kubectl create -f configmap.yml
configmap/jaeger-configuration created
~/w/j/AddPersistVolumToPods ❯❯❯
```

And I've created the elasticsearch service via StatefulSet specialized pod  (also with the new password value) from my machine to my KGE via `kubectl` command

```
~/w/j/AddPersistVolumToPods ❯❯❯ kubectl create -f elasticsearch.yml
statefulset.apps/elasticsearch created
service/elasticsearch created
~/w/j/AddPersistVolumToPods ❯❯❯
```

I can see that I have the elasticsearch service created on my GKE cluster

```
~/w/j/A/production-elasticsearch ❯❯❯ kubectl get services
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
elasticsearch   ClusterIP   None          <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   41m
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.39.240.1   <none>        443/TCP             1h
~/w/j/A/production-elasticsearch ❯❯❯
```

And I have the `elasticsearch-0` pod which have the docker container of elasticsearch service

```
~/w/j/A/production-elasticsearch ❯❯❯ kubectl  get pod elasticsearch-0
NAME              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-0   0/1     Running   0          25m
~/w/j/A/production-elasticsearch ❯❯❯
```

But when I can detail my pod on KGE, I see that my pod have some warnings and is not healthy ...

[image]

I get the pod description detail and I get this warning

```
Warning  Unhealthy              2m6s (x296 over 26m)  kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  Readiness probe failed:
```

Here, some part of my entire output to `describe` command

```
~/w/j/A/production-elasticsearch ❯❯❯ kubectl describe pod elasticsearch-0
Name:           elasticsearch-0
Namespace:      default
Node:           gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk/10.164.0.2
Start Time:     Tue, 08 Jan 2019 13:57:52 +0100
Labels:         app=jaeger-elasticsearch
                controller-revision-hash=elasticsearch-c684bb745
                jaeger-infra=elasticsearch-replica
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=elasticsearch-0
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container elasticsearch
Status:         Running
IP:             10.36.2.7
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/elasticsearch
Containers:
  elasticsearch:
    Container ID:  docker://54d935f3e07ead105464a003745b80446865eb2417da593857d21c56610f704b
    Image:         docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch@sha256:f95e7d4256197a9bb866b166d9ad37963dc7c5764d6ae6400e551f4987a659d7

                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                   From                                                          Message
  ----     ------                 ----                  ----                                                          -------
  Normal   Scheduled              27m                   default-scheduler                                             Successfully assigned elasticsearch-0 to gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  27m                   kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "data"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  27m                   kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-vkxnj"
  Normal   Pulling                27m                   kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  pulling image "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.0"
  Normal   Pulled                 26m                   kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  Successfully pulledimage "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.0"
  Normal   Created                26m                   kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  Created container
  Normal   Started                26m                   kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy              2m6s (x296 over 26m)  kubelet, gke-jaeger-persistent-st-default-pool-d72f7fde-ggrk  Readiness probe failed:
~/w/j/A/production-elasticsearch ❯❯❯
```

I go to the container log section on GCP and I get the following:

[image]

And in the audit log section I can see something like this:

```
resourceName: "core/v1/namespaces/default/pods/elasticsearch-0"     
response: {
   @type: "core.k8s.io/v1.Status"    
   apiVersion: "v1"    
   code: 500    

details: {…}    
   kind: "Status"    
   message: "The POST operation against Pod could not be completed at this time, please try again."    

metadata: {…}    
   reason: "ServerTimeout"    
   status: "Failure"    
  }
  serviceName: "k8s.io"   

status: {
   code: 13    
   message: "The POST operation against Pod could not be completed at this time, please try again."    
  }
 }
```

If I try with the original files and I change the password via KGE on GCP I get this error:

```
Pod "elasticsearch-0" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
```

After that I've create a pod, is not possible update or perform some changes?

`kubectl apply -f .....`  ? ... I suposse

How to can I change the elasticsearch password?

If I want configure a persistent volume claim on this pod, can I perform this before the `kubectl create -f`command and my volume and mountPath will be created on container and KGE?

If somebody can point me in the correct address, their support will be highly appreciated.